# Node.js regex: exclude path separator while matching files

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a folder structure like so:

```
src
|
|-- AnimalLib
|   |-- index.ts
|   |-- Animal.ts
|   |-- Mammals
|   |   |-- Cat.ts
|   |   |-- Dog.ts
|   |-- Reptiles
|   |   |-- Snake.ts
|   |-- Birds
|   |   |-- Hawk.ts
```

Assume I have the full paths of all files in an array, e.g. `['src/AnimalLib/Mammals/Cat.ts', ...]`

I would like to write a RegExp to select **only** `AnimalLib/Animal.ts` and `AnimalLib/index.ts` in a generic way, i.e. without specifying the names of the files.

I tried the following:

1. `/AnimalLib\\.*.ts/` i.e. `new RegExp('AnimalLib' + '\\' + path.sep + '.*.ts')`

   This selected files in the subdirectories of `AnimalLib`, i.e. `Birds/Hawk.ts`, `Mammals/Cat.ts`, etc.
2. `/AnimalLib\\.*?.ts/` i.e. `new RegExp('AnimalLib' + '\\' + path.sep + '.*.ts')`

   Here I tried lazily selecting `.*?.ts`, hoping it would select only the files directly under `AnimalLib/`. No dice. This also selected files in the subdirectories of `AnimalLib`
3. `/AnimalLib\\(?!\\).*.ts/` i.e. `new RegExp('AnimalLib' + '\\' + path.sep + '(?!' + '\\' + path.sep + ')' + '.*.ts')`

   Here I tried excluding the path separator with a negative lookahead, so that subfolders of `AnimalLib` could  not be selected. I am on a Windows system.

   This didn't work either.

How should I structure this regex? I am okay with using either `/.../` or `new RegExp(...)` formats.

The only thing that has worked so far is to exclude every keyboard character except `\`:

```
new RegExp('AnimalLib' + '\\' + path.sep 
    + '[- a-zA-Z0-9()\\[\\]{}\'"_!@#$%^&*?:;<>,.|]+' 
    + '.ts')
```

However, I don't like this solution since it isn't simple to reproduce.

Comment: `arr.filter(x => x.match(/\/AnimalLib\/\w*\.ts/))` if you know your file will have only letters, numbers and/or underlines.

Comment: I will have hyphens in the filename also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is using this regex `\/AnimalLib\/[^\/]*\.ts`:

```js
let arr = ['src/AnimalLib/index-app_main.ts', 'src/AnimalLib/@Animal-foo.ts', 'src/AnimalLib/Mammals/Cat.ts', 'src/AnimalLib/Mammals/Dog.ts', 'src/AnimalLib/Reptiles/Snake.ts', 'src/AnimalLib/Birds/Hawk.ts']

var results = arr.filter(x => x.match(/\/AnimalLib\/[^\/]*\.ts/));
console.log(results); // returns original values

var results2 = arr.reduce((acc, ele) => {
    var res = ele.match(/\/AnimalLib\/[^\/]*\.ts/)
    return res ? acc.concat(res) : acc;
    }, [])
console.log(results2); // retrns only matches string
```

See it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/arR5RK/1)

Comment: While this does work (and I have updated my question with a similar solution) I feel that it does not cover all cases, e.g. my file name has a hyphen in it. I only want to exclude the path separator, and allow all other characters.

Comment: humm i see, then you can use an except operator `[^\/]`. I've just edited my post and also put it a link to see it working properly. cheers!

Comment: Yup, working. To make it OS-independent, I'm updating the answer to `new RegExp('AnimalLib' + '\\' + path.sep + '([^' + '\\' + path.sep + ']+.ts)')`, which evaluates to `/AnimalLib\\([^\\]+.ts)/` on Windows. 
I'll be accepting this answer after that small edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use following regex to detect all `ts` files in AnimalLib directory only

`AnimalLib\/[^/]+?\.ts`

For testing have a look [here](https://regexr.com/3m771)

Comment: The "folder structure" was just for illustration. I actually have the full paths of each file in an array.

Comment: Please undislike the answer, if it's help:
`AnimalLib\/?()(Animal\.ts|index\.ts)`
[link](https://prnt.sc/iqy4sl)

Comment: Sorry, no can do. The question specified that the names of the files should not be part of the regex. I might have 200 files in under `AnimalLib`, it is not maintainable to list them all.

Comment: `AnimalLib\/\w+\.ts` did try this?

Comment: This last one almost works, but the escaping of slashes is incorrect. I have accepted the answer above.